# React Native [Section List ] add items dynamically on sections

Tags: react-native

I´m trying to add dynamically items to a section that is already display on the list without re rendering the list.Is this possible ?

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2
            },
        /* Added dynamically 
             {
                "id": 3
            }

        ],
        "date": "2019-03-25"
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2
            }
        ],
        "date": "2019-03-24"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
If you are storing the data in the state, you can update it by using `setState()` function.

```
this.setState({dataSource: newDataSource})
```

> eg:

```
<SectionList
....

sections={this.state.dataSource}
extraData={this.state.dataSource}

....
/>
```

It will automatically update your SectionList.

Comment: Worth noting that you may need to do a this.forceUpdate();